# Starting a first app in expo and RN - should I go with TS?

Tags: mobile, react, typescript

Coming from an ionic background, I decided it was time for me to try and make my first RN app. With Ionic I was using Typescript with my angular apps, and it was fine for me. I wanted to know if using typescript is the recommended way to work with RN and Expo nowadays - I could find everything and its contrary online about this.

I'm planning on an app that will have to integrate Redux and Redux thunk for API calls, React Navigation of course, ads and inapp purchases.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the recommended way nowadays is indeed to use Typescript. Also, React Navigation and Redux and its dependencies are all type-ready. I will go with TS then.